# How to use <f:convertNumber> to convert 103.99 to .99

Tags: jsf, number-formatting

I'm trying to get the 2-digit fraction part only using `<f:convertNumber>`. E.g. `103.99` must result in `.99`.

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.totalFare}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00" />
</h:outputText>
```

This does not work. I also tried to use the patterns `,##.00` and `,##`, but failed.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible with `<f:convertNumber>`. It's not intented to manipulate numbers (read: performing any math on it), but it's intented to format/convert it.

You should first trim off the integer part by a modulus of 1.

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.totalFare % 1}">
```

Then you can use the pattern of `.##` in order to show two fractions only:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.totalFare % 1}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern=".##" />
</h:outputText>
```